# How to extract date from csv file name and add that value in SQL Server date column using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am using SSIS to fetch data from a `.CSV` file and upload it into SQL Server 2012.

I am able to upload the data but now I have a date column in SQL Server and I have timestamp in `.csv` file name.

I would like to extract the date only (e.g. `2015-08-17`) from the `.csv` file name and then add that to date column in SQL Server after data is imported.

Example file name: `TC_001_Feature_20150814_000132`

Value need: `20150814` and added it in SQL Server column as `2015-08-14`.

Comment: You can do it with a script task that parses the file name and populates a variable with the date value, and then add it as a derived column to your dataflow, or update the date column in sql with a sql task.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, would you be able to provide a sample script that would parse the file name for data value.

Comment: No I don't have a pre-written script handy.  I'm sure if you google "string parsing" in the script language of your choice, you will find examples.

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller parts until you get to the level where you can solve it.

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate. In the linked answer, you'll see two different ways of adding the current file name into the data flow as a column. Then you'll need to use the `substring` to slice out the date part of the string, via a derived column. Then another derived column will allow you to convert the text date into an actual date.